# Dynamic content in html files, node

Tags: node.js

im new to node and i've searching ways to add dynamic data into html files, like php:

```
<?php echo $data; ?>
```

i've found that jade seems to be the exact way for node, but seems to be a little confusing, isn't there a way bit more like php?, something like:

```
{{data}} where data is var data or function, 
-data- where data is var data or function,
etc.
```

PD: im new to node and javascript, but i have experience on php, so any tutorial or book to do so will be appreciated

Comment: Look into EJS https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Comment: There's a list of template engines in Express's wiki [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki#template-engines). Handlebars or EJS are probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i recommend using [Swig js](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) and it does exactly what you are asking for, just pass the variables from the node server, in express js i use it like this:

```
res.render('index.html', {'name': 'mecha'});
```

then in my index.html i would  just use:

```
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

Comment: great, check the answer as accepted if you think its the best one